# Overriding __bases__ in a metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, metaclass

Is it possible to override the `__bases__` field of a metaclass (i.e. class deriving from `type`) using a get-set property? The following code works for *getting* `C.__bases__`, but not *setting* it:

```
class Meta(type):
    @property
    def __bases__(cls):
        print('Getting __bases__ via Meta.__bases__')
        return super().__bases__

    @__bases__.setter
    def __bases__(cls, value):
        print('Setting __bases__ via Meta.__bases__')
        super().__bases__ = value

class A: pass
class B: pass
class C(A, B, metaclass=Meta): pass

# >>> C.__bases__
# Getting __bases__ via Meta.__bases__
# (<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>)
# >>> C.__bases__ = (B, A)
# Setting __bases__ via Meta.__bases__
# AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__bases__'
```

I've tried a few substitutions for `super()` in the setter function, but none of them work:

`type.__setattr__(cls, '__bases__', value)` leads to recursion.

`object.__setattr__(cls, '__bases__', value)` gives `TypeError: can't apply this __setattr__ to type object`

So, what this boils down to is how to set the `cls.__bases__` field when it is
shadowed by a property on the metaclass. Any ideas?

---

<sup>(Yes, I am aware that defining the `__bases__` property has no effect on the actual `__mro__` of the class, although that can be arranged by overriding `mro()`)</sup>

Comment: No, you can't. Why would you want to do this, what problem does this solve?

Comment: And `super()` only supports non-data descriptors (so only `__get__`). No `__set__` is supported, so `super().__bases__ = value` will try to se the `__bases__` attribute on the super proxy, not on any base class. `__bases__` can't be altered.

Comment: Re: why I want to do this: the idea is to implement a sort of "class proxy", which forwards method and attribute access to the proxied class by copying its `__mro__`. It would then be nice if the `__bases__` of the class proxy would also correspond to the `__bases__` of the proxied class, hence the need for overriding it.

Comment: Setting `__bases__` is so very rare that not supporting that should be fine, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`super()` doesn't support data descriptors, only plain descriptors, as only `super().__get__` is implemented.

Put differently, the assignment

```
super().__bases__ = value
```

fails because the `super()` proxy object does not implement the [`descriptor.__set__()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set__), and thus that assignment tries to set `__bases__` as an attribute on that proxy object.

You'd have to manually access the descriptor on the `type` object:

```
class Meta(type):
    @property
    def __bases__(cls):
        print('Getting __bases__ via Meta.__bases__')
        return type.__dict__['__bases__'].__get__(cls)

    @__bases__.setter
    def __bases__(cls, value):
        print('Setting __bases__ via Meta.__bases__')
        return type.__dict__['__bases__'].__set__(cls, value)
```

For symmetry's sake, I've used the same manual descriptor access in the getter, although `super().__bases__` would work too.

Above, I hardcoded `type` rather than search the MRO; you could also use a helper function to find the right descriptor with a full MRO search:

```
class Meta(type):
    def _find_super(cls, name):
        mro = type(cls).__mro__
        idx = mro.index(__class__)
        for base in mro[idx + 1:]:
            if name in base.__dict__:
                return base.__dict__[name]
        return

    @property
    def __bases__(cls):
        print('Getting __bases__ via Meta.__bases__')
        return cls._find_super('__bases__').__get__(cls)

    @__bases__.setter
    def __bases__(cls, value):
        print('Setting __bases__ via Meta.__bases__')
        return cls._find_super('__bases__').__set__(cls, value)
```

Either way, now you can intercept `__bases__` being set:

```
>>> class A: pass
...
>>> class B: pass
...
>>> class C(A, B, metaclass=Meta): pass
...
>>> C.__bases__
Getting __bases__ via Meta.__bases__
(<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>)
>>> C.__bases__ = (B, A)
Setting __bases__ via Meta.__bases__
>>> C.__bases__
Getting __bases__ via Meta.__bases__
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>)
```

Comment: `__bases__` *is* writable. For example, defining C without the metaclass:


    `>>> class C(A, B): pass
    >>> C.__bases__ = (B, A)`

But your point about `super()` not supporting data descriptors explains the `AttributeError`. Thanks.

Comment: @SJPalt: I stand corrected! And on that note, I've included how to directly access the descriptor.

Comment: This is excellent, and works as expected. I hadn't thought of re-implementing `super()` like that. Thank you for your answer.